# How to open gifts in DOAX2

Tags: xbox-360, dead-or-alive-xtreme-2

"View My Collection" doesn't list gift packages, and "Send Gift" only allows me to send them. How to pack/unpack a gift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection is to track achievements, while the inventory is to use/wrap objects (via Zack Of All Trades). Open the inventory by pressing **X** when choosing an area or while at the poolside.